# Can't create KVM virtual machine with same name after initial failed attempt

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I am running on an CentOS server. I first created a KVM machine for an Ubuntu VM, but something didn't go right (I couldn't connect to the VNC session) so I aborted it. There was a warning on the first command that `virt-viewer` was missing, so I installed it. Then, I tried to launch the `virt-install` command again, to face:

```
ERROR  Guest name 'vm1' is already in use.
```

I've looked around and it seems I need to undefine/destroy it, but I get errors like:

```
$ virsh undefine vm1
error: failed to get domain 'vm1'
error: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'vm1'

$ virsh destroy vm1
error: failed to get domain 'vm1'
error: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'vm1'

$ virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
$
```

Any idea on how I find the VM and delete it so I can create it again (correctly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check under `/etc/libvirt/` and `/var/lib/libvirt/` if some stale file was left. If so, delete it and restart the `libvirt` service.

Comment: Didn't fix it either, but thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Try doing a `ps ax | grep -i vm1` to check if such a process exists. If so, kill it and restart the `libvirt` service.

Comment: I've shut down the computer and rebooted it, but I am still unable to create a VM with this name...

Comment: Try issuing `grep vm1 /etc/libvirt/ -R`. Is something shown?

Comment: Yes, there's `/etc/libvirt/qemu/vm1.xml`.  I'll delete this file. Somehow it wasn't there before, but I guess it got recreated after the boot.  It was redefined in KVM as well, so I undefined it and now it's working fine. Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 1):

May be try to restart libvirtd service. Don't worry your existing running vm is still running well during restarting this service.

Comment: This didn't fix the problem :( I ended up naming the VM differently, but I would like to know to clean up the "name cache" so to speak. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

It could be that 'vm1' domain is already in use by another user so you should undefine it with that user.

I have different storage pools and different users don't see them, so I guess with the domains happen the same.

```
[ibai@localhost ~]$ virsh pool-list --details
Name         State    Autostart  Persistent    Capacity  Allocation
-------------------------------------------------------------------
gnome-boxes  running  yes        yes         101,26 GiB   32,42 GiB

[root@localhost ~]$ virsh pool-list --details
Name       State    Autostart  Persistent    Capacity  Allocation
-------------------------------------------------------------------
default    running  yes        yes         101,62 GiB   24,14 GiB
Downloads  running  yes        yes         101,26 GiB   32,55 GiB
```

Your case could be this one:

```
[user1@localhost]$ virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------

[user2@localhost]$ virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 --    vm1                            shut_down
```

Also consider that files could be in a non default directory, so you better try to find them by the following commands or similar (be root to fetch better):

```
sudo find / -name "vm1.*"
sudo find / -name "*vm1*"
sudo find / -name "*.qcow2"
```

Comment: No, I was the only user on the system. But thanks for taking the time to answer!